# @Html.AntiForgeryToken() throwing null reference error

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm building the third more or less identical form in an MVC project (meaning I'm copying and pasting to save time). This new form, with only one control is throwing a null reference error on the @Html.AntiForgeryToken() line.

### View:

```
@model SubSheets.ViewModels.TaskItemViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateTaskItem", "TaskItems"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, "Task Name", new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

### Controller:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateTaskItem(TaskItemViewModel viewModel)
{
    /* db context actions */

    return View("../WorkItems/CreateWorkItem");
}
```

The form posts just fine, the data is saved just fine as well. However I get a null reference error, line 13:

*Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

```
Line 11: @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
Line 12: {
Line 13:     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
Line 14:     
Line 15:     <div class="form-horizontal">
```

I thought I understood the Html helper adds a hidden form field that makes sure Post request isn't coming from a third-party domain. I didn't expect to get a null reference exception from a form field?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your cshtml and view your state manually via watches or mouse over. When an exception occurs and a line is highlighted in ASP NET, chances are the exception isn't actually on that line but the surrounding lines. Is your view model instantiated?

Comment: I absolutely forgot to instantiate the viewModel... derp.. thanks Colin!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing recently.  It wasn't that the model hadn't been initialised and sent to the view; instead, it was due to a `ViewData[]` item not being initialised, but the error appeared on the `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` line which threw me for a while.